# Content script is not executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I have created Chrome extension which should change page body color. It is working when I am clicking on the extension but I want it be done when the page loads, where an alert shows that controls is passing through code, it is not calling the function.  Please help to fix this.

----------manifest.json-----------

```
{
  "name": "My Page changer",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page blue"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

> ------------------ background.js--------------------

```
debugger;
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    debugger;
        alert('I am here too ');
        /*chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"'
            //code : 'doWhatYouWant()'
        });*/
        // Execute some script when the page is fully (DOM) ready
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"doWhatYouWant();"});
    }
});


function doWhatYouWant(){
    alert('I am inside doWhatYouWant');     
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
}

// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  alert('i am here');
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `doWhatYouWant` function lives in your background page, so you won't be able to call it from a content script.

If the code you want to run is more than a couple lines long, consider putting it into a file in your extension and using the `file:` field in the *InjectDetails* parameter when you invoke `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Also, if you want it to run on every page, you can declare it as a content script in your manifest, instead of having the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener.

Answer (score 0):

There is the "prince" example on google content script tutorial:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi
I tried when learning to "google-extenioning"(?) and it works fine.
Good Luck!

eidt - uh, forgot, files are [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/)